# A question about the word 'spirit' used to mean a phonetic 'breathing'

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

The English word 'breathing' describes, among other things, the apostrophe used as a phonetic mark in front of Greek vowels. The 'rough' breathing indicates that an H should be considered present as in 'αμαρτια, *amartia*, which is then pronounced '*hamartia*'. The 'smooth' breathing is less obvious in speech.

Classically, they were referred to as the *spiritus asper* (rough) and the *spiritus lenis* (smooth).

In reading Frederick Scrivener's 'Plain Introduction' to textual analysis (published in 1861) I noticed that he referred to 'spirits' in a paragraph beginning 'Breathing and Accents' and it took me a moment to realise that he had used the word 'spirits' to mean 'breathings'.

The twenty-two categories of meaning under 'spirit' in the [**OED**](http://www.oed.com/search?searchType=dictionary&q=spirit&_searchBtn=Search) make no mention of this use of the word and I wondered whether this was an individuality of Frederick Scrivener or even a slip on his part.

A Greek scholar such as he would be very familiar with the fact that the Greek word πνευμα, *pneuma*, is translated equally both 'spirit' and 'breath' and even 'wind'.

Is this a valid way to refer, in English, to breathings ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the subject is all Greek to me (literally and figuratively), it does appear that these breathing marks were referred to as "spirits" in a number of works, all of which are pretty old.

> The spirits are two, a rough and a gentle; a rough, is a Semicircle tending towards the right hand thus ( ̔ ).
>   <sub>[An English-Greek Lexicon, containing the derivations, and various significations of all the words in the New Testament](https://books.google.com/books?id=r3ExkZJdhhcC&pg=PA428), 1661</sub>

> The Grammarians call a Spirit (or πνεῦμα) the manner of aspirating a Syllable in pronunciation.
>   <sub>[A treatise upon Greek accents [selected and] tr. from the Nouvelle methode grecque, written by the messieurs of Port Royal [really only C. Lancelot]](https://books.google.com/books?id=vupbAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA23), 1729</sub>

> Montfaucon observes, that all the most ancient manuscripts, that he has met with, are written in capitals, without accents and spirits; that accents and spirits were generally introduced into manuscripts about the seventh century...
>   <sub>[The Classical Journal, Volume 11](https://books.google.com/books?id=KZfkgJkKx_IC&pg=PA74), 1815</sub>

> The text throughout is loaded with interlineary accents, spirits, and musical notes. The spirits are of the antique mallet-shape, and the circumflex accent is of a reversed crescent form...
>   <sub>[Universal Palaeography: Oriental writing. Greek writing. Latin writing in general](https://books.google.com/books?id=up0VAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA197), 1849</sub>

Comment: I thought the intention of the question was whether it is valid to use "breathings" as a plural form of breathing. The OED defines "breathing" as uncountable so nobody has used "breathings" before. Nobody has found a need yet to use "breathing" as a countable noun. I don't object if writers invent new words as long as their meaning is obvious and the need is real. This new word - **breathing** noun (countable) - passes my test for acceptability. However, @NigelJ, I fear that only two people in this world will not just assume it is a stupid mistake. :(

Comment: @RossMurray It's "A question about the word 'spirit'", so I don't think we're answering the wrong question.

Comment: Yes, it is. The detail in the question bored me so intensely I stopped paying attention. Upon re-reading it more carefully, my guess is the original author chose "spirits" as the best option available, given that there was no plural form of "breathing" others would not just assume was a simple mistake.

Answer (score 5):

It appears from the following definitions that in phonetics “spirit” is used with the connotation you suggest:

From [Webster’s 1913 Dictionary](http://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/Spirit)

***Spirit:***

> A rough breathing; an aspirate, such as the letter h; also, a mark denoting aspiration.
>
> - (Ben Jonson)  *Be it a letter or spirit, we have great use for it*.

and from [The Chamber Dictionary](https://books.google.it/books?id=pz2ORay2HWoC&pg=PA1595&lpg=PA1595&dq=spirit%20meaning%20a%20rough%20breathing&source=bl&ots=FH4_pf70_8&sig=L9syJBZOShtzLEa_s0qdtHx1Kjw&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiMr-Hqu_vYAhXCOBQKHXtLDTcQ6AEwA3oECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=spirit%20meaning%20a%20rough%20breathing&f=false) :

***Spiritus***:

> ***spirit***, a breathing (Gr gram; spiritus asper rough breathing, spiritus lenis smooth breathing).

From [Collins Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/spiritus)

***Spiritus***:

> (Phonetics & Phonology) ***a spirit*** or breathing